# Total function for multiple input-steppers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how write a total function to call on multiple input-steppers that I used from a library. I did read the documentation of the library on how to call things. Now I can increment & decrement 1 stepper and multiply by a variable, and display in total field. I can't figure out how to change the total function so it can be used on all steppers and displayed in 1 total field. Do I need `if else` or a loop? I'm not sure how to start. Also not sure how to add library here?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function () {
    // Document ready
    $('.input-stepper').inputStepper();

  });
});


var value1 = 0.95;
var value2 = 4.00;
var value3 = 2.00;

// These are to call inputs
$('#amount1').on('increase', function (e, amount, plugin) {
  calculate();

});
$('#amount1').on('decrease', function (e, amount, plugin) {

});

$('#amount2').on('increase', function (e, amount, plugin) {

});
$('#amount2').on('decrease', function (e, amount, plugin) {

});

$('#amount3').on('increase', function (e, amount, plugin) {

});
$('#amount3').on('decrease', function (e, amount, plugin) {

});

// these are to call stepper buttons
$('[data-input-stepper-increase] ').click(function(){

});

$('[data-input-stepper-decrease]').click(function(){

});

function calculate(){
  var total = 0;
  var quantity = parseInt($('#amount1 ').val());
  total =  value1 * quantity;
  console.log(total);
  $('#TotalField').val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>$0.95 value</h3>
<button data-input-stepper-decrease>-</button>
<input id="amount1"type="text" value="0">
<button data-input-stepper-increase >+</button>

<h3>$4.00 value</h3>
<button data-input-stepper-decrease>-</button>
<input id="amount2"type="text" value="0">
<button data-input-stepper-increase>+</button>

<h3>$2.00 value</h3>
<button data-input-stepper-decrease>-</button>
<input id="amount3"type="text" value="0">
<button data-input-stepper-increase>+</button>

<label>Total</label><input type="text" 
                           class="" id="TotalField" name="TotalField" />
```

Here is link to library https://github.com/AanZee/input-stepper

link to codpen I am working on
http://codepen.io/Ongomobile/pen/kXogvZ?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the binding, both increase and decrease could be bound in one go:

```
$('[id^=amount]').on('increase decrease', calculate);
```

Instead of `'[id^=amount]'`, you could also use `'#amount1,#amount2, etc'`, but better yet would be to have a common class

For easier summarizing the values should be in a collection, such as `var values = [0.95, 4.00,  2.00];` (although you could also put them in (data) properties on the elements)

Then, if boxes is the jQuery variable of the inputs, you could summarize with:

```
var total = 0;
boxes.each(function(ind,box){ total+= values[ind] *  $(box).val();});
```

Finalizing, the whole would look like:

```
var boxes = $('[id^=amount]').on('increase decrease', calculate);  //bind the elements and assing to the boxes variable in one go

var values = [0.95, 4.00,  2.00];

function calculate(){
   var total = 0;
   boxes.each(function(ind,box){ total+= values[ind] *  $(box).val();});
   console.log(total);
     $('#TotalField').val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzdAPz?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks also will try!

Comment: Thank you so much. Don't understand binding yet but will read about it. thanks for writing better structure of code. I will learn from this, just have to get my head around it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the below solution is what you're looking for, judging from your current code:

```
var value1 = 0.95;
var value2 = 4.00;
var value3 = 2.00;

// these are to call stepper buttons
$('[data-input-stepper-increase] ').click(function(){
     calculate();
  });

 $('[data-input-stepper-decrease]').click(function(){
     calculate();
  });   

function calculate(){
      var total = 0,
      quantity1 = parseInt($('#amount1 ').val()),
      quantity2 = parseInt($('#amount2').val()),
      quantity3 = parseInt($('#amount3 ').val());

    total =  (value1 * quantity1)+(value2 * quantity2)+(value3 * quantity3);

     $('#TotalField').val(total.toFixed(2));
  }
```

Comment: @ zubair You Rock! that is exactly what it needed I am trying hard to understand javascript it's just not sinking in yet!

Comment: @MikeHaslam, you're welcome and let it take its time to sink in. :)